# How to override an array of overlaping timeslots

Tags: php, laravel

So I need to create a sort of day-per-day calendar with available times, in order for a user to be able to book a meeting with one doctor from a cabinet of multiple doctors.

I hope that this explanation is not too weird already..

Btw I use Laravel 5.5

Here's an example:

Default Schedule of the cabinet : 9:00 to 19:00

Doctor 1 says that on monday, he'll be only available from 13:00 to 15:00

Doctor 2 says that on monday, he'll be only available from 10:00 to 14:00

When I query the available timeslots :

```
$ids = Doctor::all()->pluck('id');
$workingSchedules = WorkingSchedule::whereIn('user_id', $ids)
                        ->orderBy('start_date')
                        ->whereDate('start_date', '=', $this->datetime->format('Y-m-d'))
                        ->get();
```

I get:

```
0 => [
    "start_date" => "2017-09-18 10:00:00"
    "end_date" => "2017-09-18 14:00:00"
]
1 => [
    "start_date" => "2017-09-18 13:00:00"
    "end_date" => "2017-09-18 15:00:00"
]
```

And if nothing shows up from the Database then I use the default cabinet hours.

Then I use Carbon `diffInMinutes()` method to construct an array of 30 minutes timeslots between those date range (that the user can select).

Anyway, for my script to work correcty I need to transform the result I showed you into this:

```
0 => [
    "start_date" => "2017-09-18 10:00:00"
    "end_date" => "2017-09-18 15:00:00"
]
```

As I only have two timeslots in this example it might be simple a solution, but I might also get an array of 10 timeslots that overlapse one another..

Can somebody help me find a elegant solution that will cover all possible case ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What is the role of the default schedule? It seems irrelevant to determine the outcome?

Comment: How about if doctor 1 is available from 13:00 to 15:00 and doctor 2 is available from 16:00 to 17:00?

Comment: @trincot So that if no doctor enters any working schedule, the default opening hours will be used.

Comment: @TuanDuong then the available times for the user will be 13 to 15 abd 16 to 17

Comment: @ClémentRigo, but that seems to suggest a non-reliable system. What if one doctor fills in their schedule correctly, while another forgets to do it, what reliable information can you give? Not sure if then suddenly making the whole day available, on days the first doctor is not available, is that helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To merge overlapping time-periods, you could use this code:

```
$result = [];
$i = -1;
foreach ($workingSchedules as $row) {
    if ($i < 0 || $row["end_date"] > $result[$i]["end_date"]) {
        if ($i >= 0 && $row["start_date"] <= $result[$i]["end_date"]) {
            $result[$i]["end_date"] = $row["end_date"];
        } else {
            $result[++$i] = $row;
        }
    }
}
```

`$result` will then have non-overlapping periods only.

Comment: Mh but this code won't work, you'll get Undefined offset: -1

Comment: @ClémentRigo, did you try? It is running fine on [eval.in](https://eval.in/864600). Anyway, I added a safety.

Answer (score 2):

To be easier, I will suppose $workingSchedules is an array of numbers, then we can easily compare elements

```
$workingSchedules = [
    [
        'start_date' => 1,
        'end_date' => 5,
    ],
    [
        'start_date' => 13,
        'end_date' => 16,
    ],
    [
        'start_date' => 16,
        'end_date' => 17,
    ],
];

$result = [$workingSchedules[0]];
$index = 0;
foreach ($workingSchedules as $row) {
    if ($result[$index]['end_date'] >= $row['start_date']) {
        $result[$index]['end_date'] = max($result[$index]['end_date'], $row['end_date']);
    } else {
        $index++;
        $result[] = $row;
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Above code will print:

```
[
    [
        'start_date' => 1,
        'end_date' => 5,
    ],
    [
        'start_date' => 13,
        'end_date' => 17,
    ],
]
```

1. You can custom the code to compare 2 dates instead numbers
2. If $workingSchedules is empty, we can simply return default schedule

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help.

```
$workingSchedules=array(
    0=>array(
    "start_date" => "2017-09-18 10:00:00",
    "end_date" => "2017-09-18 14:00:00"),
    1=>array(
        "start_date" => "2017-09-18 13:00:00",
        "end_date" => "2017-09-18 15:00:00"
    )
);



foreach ($workingSchedules as $schedule){
    $start=new DateTime($schedule['start_date']);
    $end=new DateTime($schedule['end_date']);

    while ($start<=$end){
        echo $start->format('Y-m-d H:i')."<br/>";
        $start=$start->add(new DateInterval('PT'.'30'.'M'));
    }
}
```